# Searching Specific Excel Cell using Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI API to read Excel file and check the quantity of products available or not. I am successfully reading excel file using below code but I am unable to read the specific cell (Quantity Column) to check weather asked product is available or not

```
    package practice;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    public class ReadingExcel {
    private static String brand = "Nike";
    private static String shoeName = "Roshe One";
    private static String colour = "Black";
    private static String size = "9.0";
    private static String quantity;

public static void main(String [] args){
    try {

        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\Project\\assets\\Shoe_Store_Storeroom.xlsx"));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row currentRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                System.out.print(cellValue + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

}

this is my excel file
[image]

Comment: Not clear where exactly your problem is. The "Quantity" column is column `E` (cell index 4). So the cell in that column is [Cell quantityCell = currentRow.getCell(4)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-).

Comment: The user will provide Brand name, Shoe Name, color, and size. Then program will tell whether the shoe is available in stock or not.

Comment: You know already how to iterate the sheet and get the cell values. So do that for each row. Get cell values of `currentRow.getCell(0)` (Brand) as `String brand`, `currentRow.getCell(1)` (Shoe Name) as `String shoeName`, `currentRow.getCell(2)` (Colour) as `String colour`,   `currentRow.getCell(3)` (Size) as `double size` and `currentRow.getCell(4)` (Quantity) as `double quantity` . Then if `searchedBrand.equals(brand)` and `searchedShoeName.equals(shoeName)` and `searchedColour.equals(colour)` and `searchedSize == size`, you have the correct row found. Then `quantity` is the quantity for that.

Answer (score 0):

using opencsv 4.1 i do this

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

...

    try (InputStream excelFile  = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);) {
        for (int numSheet = 0; numSheet < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); numSheet++) {
            Sheet xssfSheet = wb.getSheetAt(numSheet);

            xssfSheet.forEach(row -> {

                Cell cell = row.getCell(0);

                if (cell != null) {                     
                    if(StringUtils.isNumeric(cell.getStringCellValue())){

                        // Use here cell.getStringCellValue()
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below for loop:

```
for(int r=sh.getFirstRowNum()+1; r<=sh.getLastRowNum(); r++){   //iterating through all the rows of excel
            Row currentRow = sh.getRow(r);                              //get r'th row
            Cell quantityCell = currentRow.getCell(4);                  //assuming your quantity cell will always be at position 4; if that is not the case check for the header value first
            String currentCellValue = quantityCell.getStringCellValue();
            if(currentCellValue.equalsIgnoreCase(<value you want to campare with>))
                //<do your further actions here>
            else
                //do your further actions here
        }
```